# Read Stdout asynchronously to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, stdout

I have been trying to get this to work with several tutorials/answers here, but unfortunately have not been able to do so.

I want to do is to execute a process, capture its DefaultOutput and add it to a byte array.
What I got so far is:

```
private void startProcess(string path, string arguments)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Start();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
}

void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = e.Data;
    // what goes here?!
}
```

My problem now is: How do I add this data to a (growing) byte array as it comes in or is there another datatype better suited for this purpose?
Also I am not sure where to declare this destination byte array, preferably it would be somewhere in the `startProcess` Method so I can continue to work with the data after the process Exited, but how could I pass this to `p_OutputDataReceived`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a memorystream; it really does what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to use MemoryStream before but was not sucessful, I think I'll read a bit more about it. Do you have any hint how I can initialize the MS in the startProcess Method instead of defining it as static variable in the whole class?

Comment: Maybe define it as a field in your class and just do a "new" in the startProcess method? I don't think it needs to be static.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are immutable in C#, so you can't have a *growing* array. That's what `List<T>` is for.

If you don't care about character encoding, just do:

```
List<byte> OutputData = new List<byte>(); //global

void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = e.Data;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    OutputData.AddRange(bytes);
}
```

If you want an explicit encoding:

```
void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = e.Data;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); //or replace ASCII with your favorite
    //encoding
    OutputData.AddRange(bytes);
}
```

And if you really want a byte array when you're done, just do:

```
byte[] OutputDataAry = OutputData.ToArray();
```

Honestly, I think `List<string>` would be a much cleaner approach, but you ask for a `byte[]` so I give you a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read the whole output at once the following code will help you...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader reader;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c echo hi";

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        reader = p.StandardOutput;

        byte[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

if not you have to call another method than ReadToEnd and use the StreamReader in a thread to continuously read data... instead of the byte-array you can use a list or stuff like that if you want a growing collection ... check also Synchronized collections in combination with other threads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx